# MS-Project - Font Style replacement (Inactive Tasks)

Tags: vba, format, ms-project, strikethrough

I'm applying a custom macro to Stylize the entire project. But it replaces the "**Inactive Tasks**" defined style.

In addition, i can't strikethrough it as desired. Do you know how to strikethrough *TextStyles32Ex Item:19*?

Thanks a lot for support!

Here is the macro code I'm using:

```
Sub Stylize_Project()

    Dim numTasks As Long
    numTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks.Count    'Count the number of Tasks (Rows) on active Project
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    SelectAll
    Font32Ex Name:="Gill Sans MT"
    Font32Ex Size:="9"
    
    'Update Gantt Chart Titles and Font Style
    TextStyles32Ex Item:=0, Font:="Gill Sans MT", Size:="8" 'All MS Project Fonts
    TextStyles32Ex Item:=14, Font:="Gill Sans MT", Size:="8", Italic:=False, Bold:=False 'Gantt Bars Right Text Font
    GanttBarEditEx Item:="1", RightText:="Task Summary Name" 'Show task summary name in Gantt chart
    TextStyles32Ex Item:=19, Font:="Gill Sans MT", Color:=12566463 'Inactive Tasks (Gray and Strikethrough)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Francisco, I'm having trouble understanding a few things. First, why are you counting tasks? Second, why the "on error resume next"? Third, where did you get the color value for inactive tasks? It's not hex, it's not RGB and it's not HSL.